# print all data after the last delimiter

Tags: shell, awk

how can I print all data in a file after the last delimiter? the file data is like below:

```
data1
data2
######################
data3
data4
######################
data5
data6
```

I want to print :

```
data5
data6
```

as ###################### is the separator.

`*`Number of lines is unknown.

I tried:

```
$ cat file | awk -F "#"  '{print $NF}'
```

but the output is:

```
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
data6
```

Comment: If GNU awk or mawk or maybe others: `awk -vRS='######################\n' -vORS= 'END{print}' file` . If non-GNU doesn't have lazy fieldsplit, may need to add `-F` with a string that doesn't occur in your data, or at least not often.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk` with `tac` (some systems also have `tail -r` for that):

```
$ tac file | awk '/^#+$/{exit} 1' | tac
data5
data6
```

or write your own `tac`-like function if you don't have `tac` / `tail -r` already (here assuming a `cat` that supports the non-standard `-n` option and if you don't have that then use `awk -v OFS='\t' '{print NR, $0}'` instead of `cat -n`):

```
$ mytac() { cat -n -- "$@" | sort -rn | cut -f2-; }
$ mytac file | awk '/^#+$/{exit} 1' | mytac
data5
data6
```

or using any `awk` alone if you don't have `tac` and don't want to write your own:

```
$ awk '{rec=rec $0 ORS} /^#+$/{rec=""} END{printf "%s", rec}' file
data5
data6
```

or using GNU `awk` for multi-char `RS` if your file is small enough to all be read into memory at once:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= -F'(^|\n)#+(\n|$)' '{print $NF}' file
data5
data6
```

or again using GNU awk for multi-chars RS and retaining the value of the last $0 in the END section:

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)#+(\n|$)' -v ORS= 'END{print}' file
data5
data6
```

All of the above will work whether the input is stored in a file or coming from a pipe as it only reads the input once¹. If it's stored in a file (and so can be read twice) you have lots of additional options using various combinations of tools, e.g.:

```
$ tail -n +"$(awk '/^#+$/{n=NR} END{print n+1}' file)" file
data5
data6
```

---

<sup>¹ though note that for non-seekable files such as pipes, the input will need be stored temporarily by `tac`/`tail -r`/`sort`, either in memory or possibly in temporarily files. On some systems `tail -r` has a relatively low limit on how much it is willing to store (in memory).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="######################\n"; RS=""} {print $NF}' file
```

Output:

```
data5
data6
```

`$NF` contains last column.

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: FWIW that'd behave the same way in any awk but it'd fail if any of the `dataN` lines was empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fancy oneliner:

```
tail -n+$(( $(grep -nF '######################' test.txt | tail -1 | cut -d: -f1) + 1)) test.txt
```

and the more sensible separated explanation

```
last_delimiter_line=$(grep -nF '######################' test.txt | tail -1 | cut -d: -f1)
data_line_num=$((last_delimiter_line + 1))
tail -n+$data_line_num test.txt
```

- the `grep` searches the file for all delimiters and prints each match with the line number it was found on.
- the `tail` removes all but the last match
- the `cut` extracts the line number of the last delimiter found which is stored in `last_delimiter_line`
- the first line to print is one after `last_delimiter_line` and stored in `data_line_num`
- the last `tail` command prints anything from test.txt beginning at line `data_line_num`

Comment: Or simpler `tac file | sed /^######/q | tac`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - no need for `tac`: `sed 'H;/^##/h;$!d;x'`